# How to export SSRS report (.rdl) directly to PDF with OfficeWriter

Tags: excel, pdf, reporting-services, export, officewriter

I want to export a SSRS 2008 R2 (.rdl) report directly to PDF, how can i do this with OfficeWriter?
I have gone through SoftArtisans documentation, i couldn't find a way out there.
We can export an excel file to PDF but i want to export rdl directly to a PDF file.

Thanks in adv.,
Mohan.

Comment: Im able to export to PDF finally ...